# Select Tab in Helium Explorer Page

Tags: python, selenium, tabs

Im trying to have Selenium select the Activity tab on this page but cant figure out how I would select that tab.

Here is the url: https://explorer.helium.com/hotspots/112YabQcCywBonqZ8hgg213DPCvRxYxN3knSccAWfkakPjyBcaJL

```
    import bs4
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
    
    
    va = UserAgent()
    
    opts = Options()
    opts.add_argument("user-agent="+va.random)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
    
    driver.get("https://explorer.helium.com/hotspots/112xnX1tYcCs4LzS65SNs3zMXKyvtkz5kFF3EAiTkBtmShP9dTW")

    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Activity")
    link.click()
```

and im getting the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jerem/PycharmProjects/HNT-bot/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Activity")
  File "C:\Users\jerem\PycharmProjects\HNT-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Users\jerem\PycharmProjects\HNT-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\jerem\PycharmProjects\HNT-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\jerem\PycharmProjects\HNT-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Activity"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

I have no experience coding been trying to follow tutorials and nothing has been working

Comment: Have you tried any code? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @itronic1990 Just updated my post with code and errors

Answer (score 1):

The element you are trying to find is not an anchor (<a>), but a <div>, so you can't use find_element_by_link_text

Try finding the element by CSS selector instead. In your case:

```
link = find_element_by_css_selector("#rc-tabs-0-tab-4")
```

works

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Activity']").click()
```